# What is the meaning of the expression Q.E.D.? Is it similar to ■ appearing at the end of a theorem?

Tags: terminology, math-history, reference-works

I am curious about the meaning of the word Q.E.D. that is often written after a proof of a theorem (some math books use this convention).

**Edit:** Is it similar to the box being placed after a proof of a theorem? Also, what is the history of the development from Q.E.D. to ■ ?

Comment: [Q.E.D.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.) - that which was meant to be shown, has been.

Comment: Please see [*quod erat demonstrandum*.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.)

Comment: Thanks @AndréNicolas and Jared I knew it know. Another knowledge had imparted to me :-).

Comment: Hmm Google is still working today, though

Comment: Quite Easily Done.

Comment: Thanks , but why it is Quite easily done?

Comment: @JrAntalan: skytreader was joking.

Comment: Thanks @SujaanKunalan , Now I know :-).

Comment: The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.) page on Q.E.D. is actually surprisingly good (I just now looked at it). Andre originally linked to this. I'd suggest you read the entry there to fill in the gaps in mine and Jim's answers.

Comment: I was first introduced to this phrase by [Thomas Dolby](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ll4N_pvoSXI) minute 2:15 "Oh you speak french!"

Comment: A joking equivalent, $w^5$ ("which was what was wanted").

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question can be immediately answered by a google search.

Comment: Many math questions can be answered by google searches and visiting *other* sites.  I see no reason why *this* site should not have an answer.  It's relevant to math and appropriately tagged so I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @JrAntalan Why do you keep editing the question and changing the nature of it? If you are going to edit the question, then please do so by demarcating your edit by **Edit:**... that way other users can see what has changed without having to look at the edit history.

Comment: Got it @crash I edited it because it was labeled as offtopic

Comment: I figured that may have been the case. I agree with @Jim that this seems to be an appropriate question for this site--of course, a simple Google search will yield the chief meaning of Q.E.D., but many users on MSE could give more meaningful answers that gave some of the history, etc.--that is why I voted to reopen.

Comment: I also agree with you @crash

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's an abbreviation of *quod erat demonstrandum*, which is the Latin translation of a Greek phrase meaning "which had to be proven".  To the ancient Greeks, a proof wasn't complete unless the last sentence in your proof was basically the statement of the theorem. Putting QED after that sentence was their way of saying, "and that's what I was trying to prove, so there, I've proved it".

We aren't so strict about proofs anymore, but as a practical matter it's very useful to have a definitive mark that indicates the proof is over.  Some authors use Q.E.D. as that mark, some authors use the box.  There is no difference in meaning, which one is used is just a stylistic choice of the author.

**Per your edit:** The box $\Box$ is actually called a [*tombstone*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_%28typography%29).  It had long been used in magazines to indicate the end of an article.  Paul Halmos was the first mathematician to start using it to indicate the end of a proof.

Comment: Any reason why _Greeks_ would use _Latin_ in their proofs?

Comment: @oerkelens: It's the latin translation.

Comment: _Their way_ refers to Greeks putting QED after their proofs, which sounds unlikely - I understand the general idea, but the way you put it is confusing. :)

Comment: In Greek, it's "οπερ έδει δείξαι". It's a phrase that Euclid put at the end of his theorems.

Comment: It's latin for "I told you so!" ;-)

Answer (score 33):

From *A Comprehensive Dictionary of Mathematics* by Roger Thompson: "*quod erat demonstrandum*" (Latin) -- This stems from medieval translators' habitual tendency of translating the Greek for "this was to be demonstrated" to the Latin phrase above. This appeared originally at the end of many of Euclid's propositions, signifying that he had proved what he set out to prove.

Nowadays, many people do not end their proofs with *quod erat demonstrandum* or Q.E.D. but with $\Box$ or $\blacksquare$; there are other variants too, of course, but the overall meaning is to ultimately signify the end of a proof.

---

From *Encyclopedia of Mathematics* by James Tanton [supplemental]: The initials QEF, for *quod erat faciendum* (which was to be done), are sometimes added after the completion of a geometrical construction, and QEI, for *quod erat inveniendum* (which was to be found), after the completion of a calculation.

---

From *Origins of Mathematical Words - A Comprehensive Dictionary of Latin, Greek, and Arabic Roots* by Anthony Lo Bello:

[image]

Comment: I believe that the “tombstone” mark (a black rectangle) for denoting the end of a proof is due to Halmos.

Comment: @egreg Yes; in fact, I believe Halmos first used $\blacksquare$ in his 1950 book *Measure Theory* where he said: "The symbol $\blacksquare$ is used throughout the entire book in place of such phrases as 'Q.E.D.' or 'This completes the proof of the theorem' to signal the end of a proof." Apparently, he actually addressed this notation in his memoir *I Want to Be a Mathematician*:

Comment: "The symbol is definitely not my invention — it appeared in popular magazines (not mathematical ones) before I adopted it, but, once again, I seem to have introduced it into mathematics. It is the symbol that sometimes looks like ▯, and is used to indicate an end, usually the end of a proof. It is most frequently called the 'tombstone', but at least one generous author referred to it as the ‘halmos’."

Comment: My textbook uses $\blacktriangle$.

Comment: There's a small error in the Greek version: it should be `ὅπερ ἔδει δεῖξαι` (`ὅ` is masculine) and was used by Euclid. I'd agree to end proofs with Ε.Ο.Δ. :o)

Comment: I had also seen a book that uses $\spadesuit$

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the expresson Q.E.D is express quod erat demonstrandum.

Comment: This answer has nothing the other day-old answers don't.

Comment: Weird, this user seems to have pretty much disappeared after answering a bunch of questions across the network $3{1\over2}$ years ago. Never asked any questions either.